# Adding Authorization Code Grant on top of StormPath

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, stormpath

I need to build an OAuth 2.0 provider, and would like to use StormPath to keep identities and to generate access tokens and refresh tokens. However, StormPath does not support Authorization Code Grant. So, I'm considering to implement the Authorization Code Grant on top of StormPath. Is this recommended? Would you recommend a better approach?

---

What Java library and what NodeJS would you recommend for implementing OAuth 2 provider?

I like Stormpath's idea of using a JWT which doesn't need to be persisted as an access token (did I get it right?), and I want to have this in my system. So, am I right that I should use Stormpath's CustomData in order to store the authorization code, but use Stormpath API to generate a token for me? Or do I have to generate my own tokens, and use Stormpath's CustomData in order to store them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyo, I work @ Stormpath, so figured I'd hop in here.

Right now, as you probably are aware, we only support the Password Grant and Client Credentials Grant OAuth2 flows. We're working on supporting the other 2 flows (Authorization Code and Implicit) in the future, but it is a bit down the pipeline.

If you'd like to become your OWN OAuth2 provider (which I assume is what you what to do), and allow OTHER developers to build apps that log users into their websites via YOUR web service, then yes -- you will indeed need to support the Authorization Code and / or Implicit Grant types yourself.

I've worked with several people to implement this sort of thing in the past.

Typically, what I recommend, is to use an open source OAuth2 server library in whatever language you're using to handle the Authorization Code / Implicit negotiation, and then simply store the users and their tokens in Stormpath and the user's CustomData.

If you want more detail on this, please expand your question, and comment below, and I'll update my answer to reflect more detail.

---

**UPDATE**

Regarding Java libraries -- I've asked one of my coworkers who writes all our Java libraries to comment and make a recommendation for ya =) I'm a Python / Node / Go guy, sorry!

Now, regarding tokens:

- Stormpath uses JWTs to represent Access and Refresh tokens for OAuth2.
- These tokens are just 'strings', but they MUST be stored either in the browser (using cookies), or on a client device (like a mobile phone), in order to be used correctly. So yeah -- they MUST be persisted on the client!

What I would do to implement (high level), is this:

- When a user registers with your website, store them in Stormpath like normal.
- Use an OAuth2 provider library in Java to handle the Authorization Code / Implicit Grant flows on your web server. This will involve storing an Authorization Code somewhere in your database.

When a user goes to log into your app via Authorization Code / Implicit, what you'll do is this:

1. Use the Java library you have to present the user with a screen that says 'Do you except these permissions? yada yada yada...'.
2. Once the user accepts, store the Authorization Code in the Account's CustomData (you'll need this later).

When the user sends a request BACK to your server with the Authorization Code, and wants to get an Access Token, you'll need to:

1. Grab the Account's CustomData.
2. Grab the Authorization Code out of CustomData, and validate it is the same one the user is sending to you.
3. If it's valid, then generate a JWT Access Token for the user using a JWT library in Java. I recommend JJWT: https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt

When a user sends Access Tokens to your server to identify themselves, you'll need to:

- Validate the JWT.
- Grab the user's HREF out of the JWT (something like https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/xxx).
- Fetch the user account from Stormpath (by href).
- Use that user object for whatever you need =)

Hopefully that makes sense!

It might sound like a lot of work, but in reality, this should be very simple. You really only need the OAuth2 library to help you handle the OAuth2 POST request data properly, and help with things like:

- Defining permissions (scopes).
- etc.

Comment: Thanks! I'll expand my question for more details.

Comment: rdegges, please see the expanded question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: rdegges, thanks a lot! You mentioned you're a NodeJS + Python guy, so can recommend a library for OAuth 2 provide in NodeJS? and in Python?

Comment: @AdiLevin sure! In python, Oauthlib is the best option: https://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html. In Node, Oauth2 sever is your best bet: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-oauth2-server

Comment: rdegges, I followed your advice, and looked at node-oauth2-server. I see there is a requirement that the model object shall implement saveAccessToken (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-oauth2-server#saveaccesstoken-accesstoken-clientid-expires-user-callback), and similarly getAccessToken. If I am going to use a stateless JWT for the access token, like the tokens that Stormpath provides, should I just provide a trivial implementation and avoid saving, or should I store the access token in Stormpath's CustomData?

Comment: I'd store the token in CustomData, that way you can easily extract / verify it =)

Answer (score 2):

I am Stormpath's Java Developer Evangelist.

The Java SDK supports the Authorization Code Grant type via SAML providers and social providers, such as Facebook and Google.

The higher level integrations, like Servlet, Spring and Spring Boot currently support external provider auth flows via Stormpath's ID Site service.

We are working to integrate support for those flows directly into the integrations. You can track progress on that [here](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/milestones/1.0.0).

If you want to implement the ability to *be* an Authorization Code grant type provider, I would recommend using the [Apache Oltu](http://oltu.apache.org/) library. You could still integrate Stormpath with Oltu using the Stormpath Java SDK.

Comment: Thanks, afitnerd! Indeed, what I want is to be an authorization code grant type provider. I'm a little surprised that Oltu is recommended. It seems to be poorly documented. Anyway, I'm assuming you have good reasons for recommending it. I'll look for resources to help me get started. If you can point me to a sample implementation, or a guide that will help me with this, it will be great :-)